# Environment Variable for external storage/removable disks?

Tags: variables, batch-file, autohotkey, environment, removable-storage

I have a Seagate Backup Plus Drive, and a FreeAgent GoFlex Drive. When I plug them in, they alternate between (E:) and (F:). I need to write a script that can be accessed on any computer, or any drive letter.

I'm using Win7x64, I don't think LD_LIBRARY_PATH is the answer here...

Does anyone know how to link to it?

Comment: Try using `DriveGet` for the drive labels : http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/DriveGet.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use [DriveGet](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/DriveGet.htm), for example to get a list of removable drives:

```
; put drive letters of removable drives into variable 'drives'
DriveGet, drives, list, REMOVABLE
Loop, Parse, drives  ; loop through each character (drive letter) in drives
{
  DriveGet, labelName, label, %A_LoopField%:  ; get the drive label
  MsgBox Drive %A_LoopField%, Label=%labelName%
}
```